# 'Files' icon on lock/login screen

Tags: 20.04, files, icons, screen, lock

Recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and noticed something upon the fresh install that I hadn't seen in earlier versions: a small files icon on the bottom of the inlog screen (as pictured in the screengrab), that I cannot actually interact with or use. What is the meaning of this icon and should it be there? If not, how should I make sure all works as intended and fix the issue? Is there some security risk involved with this icon on the lock screen?

Thanks for the input!

[image]

Comment: If you click on it, what does it do?

Comment: Nothing! It's just.. there?

Answer (score 1):

This occurred for me as well 22.04, this is what did the trick for me to stop it from showing up.

Settings > Notifications > Files

- Uncheck `Lock screen notifications`